# Jquery access to $(this) inside a plugin

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to get an access to $(this) when the plugin is initialized? for example I have a plugin resizable where I need access to an element that is being resized, so I could use it later in a method that is declared inside a plugin

```
$('.someClass').resizable({  
  resize:function(event, ui) {
   $(this).doSomeStuff() //how to get access to $(this)? Where it should be declared?
  }
})
```

I've figured out the solution:

```
$('.someClass').each(function(){ 
  var me = $(this); 
  $(me).resizable({     
    resize: function(event, ui) { 
          $(me).doSomeStuff();
        }
   });
});
```

All that it took just to make sure the plugin is inside of $('').each() method

Comment: That seems pointless. `this` will be set to the element being resized anyway; your two code examples have the same effect, with the exception of the second being much slower.

Comment: no they don't have the same effect. I have tested it myself before posting.

Comment: "Resizable" wraps the elements in a div, and in the "resize" function "this" referes to that wrapping div, not the original element. That is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

its a problem of scope, so cache the element in a variable:

```
var elem = $('.someClass');
elem.resizable({  
  resize:function(event, ui) {
   elem.doSomeStuff() //how to get access to $(this)? Where it should be declared?
  }
});
```

**edit**

n.b. logging 'event', 'ui' to the console should clarify what those args provide you with, also check the api docs: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Resizable

```
$('.someClass').resizable({  
  resize:function(event, ui) {
   console.log(event);
   console.log(ui);
  }
});
```

Comment: ..though look at the documentation for the plugin, probably you can access the element through the 'event' or 'ui' args passed to the resize fnc...

Comment: this will work correctly only if there is one element on a page, it is a reference to a class but not to the element being resized now, There is an access through the event, but I don't know how to assign a method to an event.target

Comment: @tylik: sure :) I realised my answer is too simplistic .. see my comment above

Comment: yeah the docs suck for this .. try: 'console.log(ui)' inside resize.. same with the 'event' arg .. should clarify :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("textarea").resizable({
    stop: function (evt, ui) {
        $(this).find(':input').focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: I know how to set reference to this inside a plugin, but I don't want to mess up in ui, just want to get $(this), when the plugin is initialized

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you are going for, then. Could you edit your question, giving more code, and calling lots of attention to the particular spot where you want $(this), and what you want it to be?

Comment: ok. it's simple, The resizable is a textarea, and I want it to focus when it is resized, the code should  look like this -- $(this).focus();

Comment: Edited. That should focus a textarea after it has been resized.

Comment: Instead of "ui.element" you can do "this". The key trick to note is that what you are resizing is a wrapper around the textarea, and not the textarea itself. So if you want to focus it, you need to find it.